# Users on my site are getting blank pages after logging in

Tags: 2013

Multiple users are telling me that they just get a blank screen after logging into the site. When they refresh the page, it asks them to log in again. They should have access to the site because they are using their domain 3 accounts, and I've added all domain 3 users as visitors to the site. Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like there were changes to your default site "home" page (e.g. default.aspx).  Things to check:

- default.aspx was deleted (though I would expect this to result in a 404 error)
- permissions to default.aspx were changed or removed
- a non-existent or blank page was made the default site page

Comment: They were actually using incorrect passwords. They changed their passwords to their E-mail accounts, which use the same domain as our sharepoint site, but their true domain accounts still had the old passwords. They were getting blank pages because that's what happens when you keep trying to log in using the wrong password.

Comment: Sounds like you need to add an "unauthorized access" error page to help diagnose those issues.  Glad you found your resolution.